# How to create a form element whose name is an array, using Blade? (Laravel-4)

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a form which loops through an array to create the form elements, so the name of each input element must be an array element. It's easy to do this with plain old PHP:

```
<input type="text" name="dt[<?php echo $dues_type_id ?>]" ... />
```

where $dt is the array whose indices are dues types ids.

No matter what combination of quotes and curly braces I use, I cannot make this work using Blade. For example, this does not cause an error message, but it doesn't work:

```
{{ Form::text( 'dt[{{{ $dues_type_id }}}]', $display_amount) }}
```

The source code for the Blade construction is this:

```
<input name="dt[&quot;$dues_type_id&quot;]" type="text">
```

Of course, I could just code this in PHP, but I already have all of my CSS formatting set up with Blade, and besides -- this SHOULD be possible, and I'm frustrated because I can't figure out how to do it. I'm sure I'm missing something easy... Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `{{ Form::text( 'dt[' . $dues_type_id . ']', $display_amount) }}` instead?

Comment: Thanks! That works. Appreciate it!